# How do I force a constant C-expression evaluation for use as a constant in a .S file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, macros

A header file I'm including from `/usr/include/**/asm` (rudely?) uses simple C expressions to express an offset from a base value, i.e.:

```
#define __NR_exit                       (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+  1)
```

Of course, when I `#include` this into my `.S` file the resulting preprocessor-produced asm says:

```
start.S|17| Error: garbage following instruction -- `ldr r7,=$(0+1)'
```

So, crazy as it sounds, I guess I want the C-preprocessor (or the assembler) to constexpr-evaluate the macro so it can actually be used, despite the C arithmetic `+` operator and parens in there -- what is the right way to go about doing this?

Please note that this isn't inline asm, but an "out of line" `.S` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aw boo, it was just because there was an erroneous dollar sign. If you change it to:

```
ldr r7,=__NR_exit
```

it seems to compile just fine. I guess `as` supports basic arithmetic expressions in positions where it expects constants.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is ISA-specific. On ISAs where parentheses are valid grouping operators in asm constants, it works fine. In x86 asm, however, parentheses are part of the mnemonic syntax for effective-address/dereferencing. I suspect Linux's headers avoid the issue on such archs by writing out the numbers explicitly, but you should be aware that this solution is by no means universal and it only *happens to work* on the arch(s) you're looking at...

Comment: @R.: Parsing assembly source is a function of the assembler, not the ISA. Nor is this an issue with parentheses used for addressing; assembly syntax typically distinguishes immediate values (as by introducing them with “=” or “$”) in a way that allows them to contain parentheses for grouping without being confused as addressing.